# create_admin aborted! undefined method `source_index' for Gem:Module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Trying to get gitorious running..

I got undefined method `source_index` for Gem:Module from env RAILS_ENV=production ruby1.8 script/create_admin

When I run:

`env RAILS_ENV=production ruby-1.8.7-p371 script/create_admin`

I got:

```
NOTE: Gem.source_index is deprecated, use Specification.
It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem.source_index called from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371/gems/rails- 2.3.18/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:21.
```

Please see here: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=YgV9Sym7 and here: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=3LYTygS0

Answer (score 1):

My view is that:

Latest stable release of ruby is 1.9.3, since you are using older version of ruby you have to use ruby gems which is compatible with 1.8.7 version...which is something like:

```
gem update --system <your desired ruby gem version>
```

Answer (score 1):

i just run the following command and it works  for me

```
rvm install rubygems 1.4.2 --force
```